# Put conemu tabs in own windows

Tags: conemu

I had this set up earlier today but a crash wiped out my configuration file and now I can't work out how to get it back.

How can I configure ConEmu so that my tabs run as independent "windows" that I can position independently on my screen? i.e I want tab1 on monitor1, and tab2 on monitor2.

This seems to be related to the fact that when I close any of my tabs using the Windows close (X in the top right) it closes *all* of my tabs, which I don't want.

- I don't mean how to split a tab in the same window

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

- Disable multiple consoles in one conemu window option
- Dont start a new task with my new-tab shortcut, create a new window